# React.createElement with typescript error when trying to pass props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create dynamic components in react + typescript but I am struggling to correctly type the props on it.

Here is a simpler version of what I'm doing.

```
interface ComponentProps {
  title: string;
}

interface ArrInterface {
  component: FC<ComponentProps>;
  title: string
}
 
const Arr: ArrInterface = [
  { component: FooComponent, title: "foo"},
  { component: FooComponent, title: "bar"}
];

const FooComponent: FC<ComponentProps> = ({title}) => {
  return <div>{title}</div>
}

const BarComponent: FC = () => {
  return sectionsArr.map((section) => {
    const {component, title} = section;
    return React.createElement(component as FC, { title })
  })
}
```

this is the error I am getting :

> Argument of type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type ' Attributes'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type 'Attributes'

it works if I do a ts-ignore on top of that line btw :)

Can someone please help me out on this one? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself :)

For those ending up with the same issue as I did, it turns out you need to pass the props type to createElement function.

So basically instead of doing

```
    return React.createElement(component as FC, { title })
```

this should fix the issue

```
    return React.createElement<ComponentProps>(component as FC, { title })
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature that TS uses for your `React.createElement` is

```js
function createElement<P extends {}>(
    type: FunctionComponent<P>,
    props?: Attributes & P | null,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): FunctionComponentElement<P>;
```

In your `React.createElement(component as FC, { title })` call, you're passing a value (`component`) with the type `FC` as the argument named `type`. `FC` is defined as

```js
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

So since you asserted `component as FC` — without a type argument — TS now uses the default type for the type argument `P`, namely `{}`. Now the type of the `props` argument is `Attributes & {}`, which is the same as just `Attributes`. And just like TS tells you, the property 'title' does not exist in type 'Attributes'.